# How to "run" an HTML webpage without Express, etc

Tags: node.js, cors, require

My question can be pretty similar to others, but I already read a lot of answers, but I don't understand completely the details behind them.

I have to create a node.js REST API, but I don't took any lessons before. So i'm currently reading and trying tutorials to learn to create a simple node.js script.

I installed node.js, i created my script (it's just reading an input field), and when i click on a button, it's supposed to write the input in the console.

The tutorial needs only node.js, and use the .createserver. I understand that node.js is server side and can't be interpreted without it.
The tutorial asks to open the .html file in the browser, directly with the path. The html webpage shows up, but... When i'm pressing "ok", here's the errors :

```
*app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///.../ApplicationAngular/nodeProject/app.html?name=' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

GET file:///.../ApplicationAngular/nodeProject/app.html?name= net::ERR_FAILED*
```

All the threads on StackOverflow explains that I need a third-party to run the HTML webpage. But on the tutorial, everything is working fine and never mentions the existance of Express, Cheerio, etc..

Here's the samples of code:
app.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name"/>
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="valid()"/>
<div id="message"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script>
function valid() {
    $.get('', { name: $('#name').val() }, function(data) {
        $('#message').html(data.message);
    }, 'json');
}
</script>
```

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true); 
    var name = url_parts.query.name;

    if(name){
        console.log('Nom: ' + name);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({message: 'Hello' + name + ' !'}));
    } else {
        console.log('No name !');
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        fs.readFile('app.html', function (err,data)
        {
            res.end(data);
        });
    }
   
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Is the tutorial missing something? Do I have to install Express in order to view the page web?
Sorry again, english is not my native langage.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line in your html

```
<script src="app.js"></script>    <!-- wrong! -->
```

you try to run your nodejs program in your browser's javascript interpreter. You need to run it on your server instead. Your browser gacks on the `require()` operations because those are made to work in nodejs on your server.

Try removing the line from your html, and try doing something like this on your server's command line, then visiting http://localhost:1337 from your browser.

```
 node app.js
```

The fact that browsers and nodejs support the same language is a bit confusing as you figure this all out. The language is the same but the two runtime environments are quite different.  Be patient. You'll get it.

The `app.js` nodejs program you showed us should function correctly. In its `if (name)` branch it handles the request coming from the `$.get()` operation in the browser. In its `else` branch it delivers the html file to the browser.

And, it has to be said, doing more than just this kind of tutorial with nodejs alone -- without express or some other webserver framework -- gets to be a huge pain in the xxx neck, enough of a pain in the neck that you'll be tempted to develop your own framework.

**Edit** You have this line twice

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});   /* wrong! */
```

Change both occurrences to

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

The `Content-Type: text/html` header tells your browser to interpret your html file as html, not raw text.

Comment: Thanks for you answer !
Actually, i already run the command you gave me, i can access it to http://localhost:1137, but the webpage doesn't show up :( I have just my "Hello Word", and nothing else.
So I tried to add it in an src line, to try something else because i saw it on another thread.

But yeah, none of this make the script functionning....

Yeah, I heard a lot of good from Express but I was trying to learn thing bit by bit. Think I'll find a tutorial with Express !

Comment: Please see my edit.  And remember, View Source... is your friend.

Comment: And, jquery 1.10 is *really* old.  Use https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js

Comment: Hi again! I updated my first project with your advices :
- Installed Express
- Replaced my version of Jquery

And it's so much better ! Way less errors about CORS , etc.. And I understand better the functionment.

I discovered new ways of importing (I have Node version 14, Express v6 and TypeScript 4.1 now) but I'm stuck of this error again (require is not defined). But I'm already on my way to find a solution. Thanks again ! :)